# Reusing an InputSource through application life cycle

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am using InputSource to parse a large xml file (1.2 mb). I need to keep this InputSource in memory. I do not want to keep loading it. What's the best why to do this? I have tried using a singleton, but the Sax Parser complains that the document is missing an end tag after the 2nd time the object reference is accessed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cfr_title_index);    
InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(ins);
MySinglton.xmlInput = xmlSource;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams are "read once".  You should not plan to hang onto it.  If you need its contents in memory, read them into an object or data structure and cache it.